# localhost port not matching with apache port

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, localhost

i'm really new to web development and was trying to explore different projects on github. i downloaded a react "nearby restaurant finder" project and opened it on vs code. then i looked up how to run the project on a localhost and these are the steps i followed:

1. downloaded xampp and started apache on it. The port number it showed was 80. when i searched localhost:80 on chrome it directed me to the xampp dashboard.
2. i then transferred the project (which i downloaded from github) folder into the htdocs folder in xampp directory
3. then i opened a terminal in the project in vscode and ran the command "npm install", then "npm start"
4. i think my npm start worked fine because it opened up the localhost tab in chrome, only it showed "localhost refused to connect". also the url showing at the top had "3000" as port number. (http://localhost:3000/)
5. tried a couple of things (disabled firewall, cleared dns cache) nothing worked
6. then i figured i should match the port numbers. in the package.json file under scripts i put `"start": "SET PORT = 80 && react-scripts start"` then did npm start.
7. It told me the port is already being used (which i don't understand why) and to type yes if i want to run the project on another port instead, i did so.
8. then it opened a localhost with port number 81 and still the same "localhost refused to connect message"
9. the i tried changing the port number of apache to 3000 and removing SET PORT = 80 from scripts. this time when i did npm start it led me to localhost with port number 3001 and still the same error

i'm not able to understand where i'm going wrong. what can i do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the GitHub repo of said project?

Comment: @prohit here, https://github.com/elharony/Nearby-Restaurants

Comment: i also tried doing the same with a different github project: https://github.com/myanhtle/Restaurant-Finder . but facing the same problems :(

Comment: The linked repositories don't require a webserver for development or getting them to run locally. You should first install their dependencies with `npm install` and then run `npm start` to start them locally. No database/external webserver needed. For the first repository, you'll need a  Google Console API key, but that's documented in the repository.